# fragmentManager и RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, android-sdk

Логично ли передавать fragmentManager в RecyclerView для "переключения" фрагментов? Возникнут ли утечки памяти? Если нелогично, опишите пример реализации.

Comment: Правильнее было бы создать в ресайклере слушатель (listener) и, когда потребуется переход, уведомлять из ресайклера фрагмент / активность через этот листенер.  В противном случае возможны утечки памяти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RecyclerView не должен знать ничего о сущностях которые находятся за его пределами. Так вы нарушаете ["Принцип единой ответственности"](https://medium.com/webbdev/solid-4ffc018077da).

Задача RecyclerView - рисовать список. И единственные сущности о которых он должен знать - это модели которые отображают состояние вашего Item-а.

- Если вы добавите туда FragmentManager - то вы больше не сможете использовать ваш RecyclerView в сущностях где нет FragmentManager.
- Если вы захотите переиспользовать это адаптер в другом месте и там к примеру по клику должна будет открываться активити, то ваш адаптер будет знать о FragmentManager, который ему будет совершенно не нужен.
- Ну а если в самом адаптере будет жестко зашита логика клика, то вы в принципе не сможете изменить поведение клика для разных кейсов.

**Решение**

Создаете интерфейс вроде такого:

```
interface OnItemClickListener {

    void onItemClick(item: YourModelClass)
}
```

В активити:

```
class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    // другие методы активити

    @Override
    void onItemClick(item: YourModelClass) {
        // ваша логика по клику на элемент списка. Здесь вы можете свободно использовать ваш FragmentManager
    }
}
```

В адаптере:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<YourModelClass> items;
    private OnItemClickListener clickListener;

    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(List<YourModelClass> items, OnItemClickListener clickListener) {
        this.items = items;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickListener.onItemClick(items.get(position));
            }
        });
    }

    // другие методы адаптера

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
}
```